# Dynamic variable using self.var

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if we can use a dynamic variable using "self.variable"

I currently have this class which has two maps. I have a function that apply various things to the map. I want to change map on the fly calling my function with the current map in variable.

```
googleMap = Class.extend({
    map: null,
    miniMap: null,
    isOverlayVisible: false,
    overlay: null,
});
```

My script has the following code.

```
 self.map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

`self.map` refers to a variable defined in the class. I also have the variable `self.minimap`.

How could I have the 'map' inside variable like the following:

```
function updateMap(currentMap){

    if(typeof currentMap !== "undefined"){
        currentMap = map;
    }
    var currentMap = 'minimap';

    self.currentMap.fitBounds(bounds);
}

updateMap('minimap');
```

Thanks.

Comment: `self[currentMap]`

Comment: Worth reading: [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: One note I'd like to add: while `self` is not a reserved word, it is a global variable that refers to the current execution context (i.e. the window or the worker global scope). You might want to be careful hiding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access Object property by two way

one is `.` and second is `[variable or string]`

```
self[currentMap].fitBounds(bounds);
```

See this
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors.